# How to add a downloadButton in the header of a shiny Dashboard

Tags: javascript, r, shiny, shinydashboard

I want to have a `downloadButton` on my `shiny Dashboard` that download a .pdf that I have in the *www* folder which explain how to use the dashboard.

So far I have successfully added a `Home Button` and a `GitHub` link (window.open) but I can't find a way to implement `downloadButton`.

So far here is my code:

header.R:

```r
header <- dashboardHeader(title = "Support Vector Machine - Credit Fraud",
                          titleWidth = 400,
                          tags$li(a(onclick = "onclick =window.open('https://github.com/xxx/xxx')",
                                    href = NULL,
                                    icon("github"),
                                    title = "GitHub",
                                    style = "cursor: pointer;"),
                                  class = "dropdown"),
                          tags$li(a(onclick = "openTab('foa')",
                                    href = NULL,
                                    icon("home"),
                                    title = "Homepage",
                                    style = "cursor: pointer;"),
                                  class = "dropdown",
                                  tags$script(HTML("
                                       var openTab = function(tabName){
                                       $('a', $('.sidebar')).each(function() {
                                       if(this.getAttribute('data-value') == tabName) {
                                       this.click()
                                       };
                                       });
                                       }")))


)
```

server.R :

```r
server <- function(input, output, session) {

  observeEvent(input$home, {
    updateTabItems(session, "sidebar", "foa")
  })
}
```

The result is:

[image: code screenshot]

I just want to add a `downloadButton` next to the `GitHub` icon where it is written "How to use this Dashboard" and when you click on it, it downloads a .md or .pdf that I have on my *www* folder.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do this by adding another `tag` for download button (say your pdf file is saved under subfolder called `img` under the folder `www`).

```
 tags$li(a(id = "download", class = "fa fa-download",
           href = "/img/how_to.pdf", download = "how_to.pdf"), class = "dropdown")
```

So appending to your existing header code:

```
header <- dashboardHeader(title = "Support Vector Machine - Credit Fraud",
                          titleWidth = 400,
                          tags$li(a(onclick = "onclick =window.open('https://github.com/xxx/xxx')",
                                    href = NULL,
                                    icon("github"),
                                    title = "GitHub",
                                    style = "cursor: pointer;"),
                                  class = "dropdown"),
                          tags$li(a(onclick = "openTab('foa')",
                                    href = NULL,
                                    icon("home"),
                                    title = "Homepage",
                                    style = "cursor: pointer;"),
                                  class = "dropdown",
                                  tags$script(HTML("
                                       var openTab = function(tabName){
                                       $('a', $('.sidebar')).each(function() {
                                       if(this.getAttribute('data-value') == tabName) {
                                       this.click()
                                       };
                                       });
                                       }"))),

                          ## DOWNLOAD
                          tags$li(a(id = "download", class = "fa fa-download",
                                    href = "/img/how_to.pdf", download = "how_to.pdf"),
                                    class = "dropdown")



)
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This is from another forum someone had the same question. And this worked for that person.

```
   > downloadButton
    function (outputId, label = "Download", class = NULL, ...) 
    {
        aTag <- tags$a(id = outputId, class = paste("btn btn-default shiny-download-link", 
            class), href = "", target = "_blank", download = NA, 
            icon("download"), label, ...)
    }
    <bytecode: 0x000000001a919c58>
    <environment: namespace:shiny>
```

This is the function behind the Download button. Just use your own function.

```
customDownloadbutton <- function(outputId, label = "Download"){
    tags$a(id = outputId, class = "btn btn-default shiny-download-link", href = "", 
           target = "_blank", download = NA, icon("accessible-icon"), label)
}
```

Just insert in `icon` the icon you want and use the function like the normal downloadbutton

How to use it:

```
customDownloadbutton <- function(outputId, label = "Download"){
    tags$a(id = outputId, class = "btn btn-default shiny-download-link", href = "", 
           target = "_blank", download = NA, icon("accessible-icon"), label)
}

library(shiny)


ui <- fluidPage(


   titlePanel("Old Faithful Geyser Data"),


   sidebarLayout(
      sidebarPanel(
         sliderInput("bins",
                     "Number of bins:",
                     min = 1,
                     max = 50,
                     value = 30),
         customDownloadbutton("myDownloadButton")
      ),


      mainPanel(
         plotOutput("distPlot")
      )
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I want to get the `downloadButton` into the header of my Dashboard. I get the following error: `ERROR: Expected tag to be of type li`.